# is it possible to pull images of the internet with Google app script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I was wondering if it was possible to use Google app script to search for an image using a key word and then pull that image into a document or spreadsheet and if so how. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use URLFetchApp to fetch the image and store the blob in Drive.

```
var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(IMAGE_URL).getBlob();
var file = DriveApp.create(blob);
```

Comment: is it possible to use a keyword to fetch an image? ex: search cat and pull the first image off the a image Google seach

Comment: actually i found half a solution. you can use the Google image search URL and change the  keyword in the URL to change the search but i still don't know how to fetch the first image off the page. https://www.google.com/search?q=person&espv=2&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=Lq1VU8eMJ-nMsATupIEY&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAQ&biw=1680&bih=892